# Sampling with SAS

Tags: sas, sampling

I'm fairly new to SAS and I've inherited apiece of code which selects rows from a sample frame and puts them into another dataset as the sample. 758 is the number of rows it samples. srno appears to be a simple serial numbering system.

```
data FinalSample;
   srno=0;
   SampSize = 758; 
   ObsLeft = Totobs;    
   do while (SampSize > 0); 
      PickIt +1;    
      if ranuni(0) < SampSize / ObsLeft then do;    
         set SampleFrame point = PickIt nobs = TotObs;
         srno = srno + 1;   
         output;    
         SampSize = Sampsize - 1;   
      end;  
      ObsLeft = ObsLeft - 1;    
   end; 
   stop;    
run;
```

It looks to me as if this is just a simple random sample. Is that the case? I was wondering if the code would be easier to understand if I was to move into a `Proc SurveySelect` command.

Would there be any different between the code above a survet select with `method = SRS` and `samplesize = 758`?

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are correct in your assumption (simple random sampling without replacement).

The main advantage of using `proc surveyselect` is that it makes the code much easier for someone else to understand what it is doing.  And of course, why write a long piece of code when there is a built in procedure that does exactly the same thing.

One addition you should make to the code is to add a seed, so that the same results can be replicated in future if necessary.  It is very bad practice not to put this in, for example you will never be able to replicate the same 758 rows with the code you have posted.

One final point, if you do decide to stick with the code then consider switching from `ranuni` to `rand`.  `Rand` is an updated version of `ranuni` (utilising an improved random number algorithm) and therefore is likely to be supported by SAS for a longer time.

Comment: Thank you for what looks to me like a very good answer. Good points about the seeding and the random number algorithim.

Can you think of any reason why someone would do it like this?

Comment: I think of two simple reasons. 1) Speed. The algorithm should be very fast since only the selected records are read from disk. 2) The code already existed and perhaps even existed before PROC SURVEYSELECT was created.

Comment: I assumed that the second may be the case, however, given the size of the database performance may be an issue so I think some testing is in order.

Thank you for your help.